# Convex optimization task

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

So I have the optimization task where f(x) and g1(x),g2(x) are given. And i need to find optimal value of function. Answer should be like (x=(x,x),f=f). Please help if you know how to do this)

f(x<sub>1</sub>,x<sub>2</sub>) = (x<sub>1</sub> - 2)<sup>2</sup>  + (x<sub>2</sub> - 3)<sup>2</sup> + x<sub>2</sub><sup>3</sup> → min

g<sub>1</sub>(x<sub>1</sub>,x<sub>2</sub>) = x<sub>1</sub> + x<sub>2</sub> ≤ 2.5

g<sub>2</sub>(x<sub>1</sub>,x<sub>2</sub>) = -x<sub>1</sub> + 3x<sub>2</sub> ≤ 4

x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub> ≥ 0

Comment: There are several approaches. What techniques are you given for doing convex optimization?  Do you know any results  that may help?

Comment: I think using Karush-Kuhn-Tucker condition but not for sure

Comment: What have you tried to write out the KKT conditions? They are actually really clear stated, or see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) for reference.

Comment: You can also plot the region of all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ that satisfy your constraints, and see if you have an interior point solution or boundary point solution.